# Acer TravelMate B1 TMB118-M-C0EA можно ли к нему подключить hdd/ssd sata 2.5 дюйма?

Tags: железо, hdd, ssd, ноутбук

Подскажите если кто то сталкивался, ноутбук: Acer TravelMate B1 TMB118-M-C0EA, вот ссылка на него на DNS https://www.dns-shop.ru/product/eb1507283e943332/116-noutbuk-acer-travelmate-b1-tmb118-m-c0ea-cernyj/
Если посмотреть на фотки, то внизу вроде как есть отсек под SATA SSD/HDD диск на 2.5 дюйма. Тут зашёл в магазин, уже думал купить, у продавца спрашиваю о возможности подключения диска, он говорит нет нельзя, как говорит и встроенный SSD нельзя заменить, так как последний запаян. Решил повременить с покупкой.

Пришёл домой, стал искать инфу. Кто то пишет что можно SATA SSD поставить. А кто то нет, а кто то пишет что можно только в комплекте нет SATA шлейфа, его нужно отдельно купить, разобрать ноут и подключить - тогда можно поставить диск. Может быть кто то сталкивался или знает, как на самом деле с подключением SATA диска дела обстоят у этого ноутбука?

Comment: С подобными ноутами очень сложно. Бывает, что модели отличаются в одну циферку, а в железе - полностью (у меня есть acer aspire, я знаю). Но если что, то я бы этот ноут не брал - скорее всего там распаянная память и добавить еще хотя бы 4 будет невозможно. А в 2021 году покупать ноут с 4 гигами памяти немного неразумно.

Comment: >>А в 2021 году покупать ноут с 4 гигами памяти немного неразумно - дело в том что если Вы посмотрите у него цена менее 14 тыс рублей. И процессор 4-х ядерный с кешем 4 Мб + компактность 11.6 дюйма которая очень меня привлекает, я примерялся по сравнению с 14 дюймами он бы очень хорошо вписался. Да - разрешении НЕ 1920, при этом что то примерно с такими параметрами 14 дюймов стоит от 23 тыс, а если 13.5 хотя бы то ближе к 30. Поэтому по совокупности факторов он бы мне подошел для задач которые можно делать в дороге. Вот SSD мне бы ещё, чтобы + 240 Гб было.

Comment: я тоже так думал, а потом понял, что глаза вот они, их не купишь, нервы тоже свои не купишь. Но бюджет такая штука коварная. Но все же, выбранная модель - это очень и очень слабая. на ней даже интернет нормально не посерфить.

Comment: Тут дело ещё и в том, что мой текущий 14-ти дюймовый атом и слабее, и больше и аккумулятор хуже держит и оперативки всего 2 гб. Так что прогресс с этой моделью у меня явно был. По зрению кстати не замечал ничего подобного, доводилось на 10-ти дюймовом планшете irbis с клавиатурой поработать. 2-3 часа с понедельника по пятницу - вполне нормально, не уставал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получилось подключить SSD, но пришлось на али заказать шлейф за 1500 рубликов (называется там PCNANNY для acer TMB118 HDD DRIVE CABLE test good). Дороговато.

Comment: Благодарю, тоже судя по отзывам в интернете подумал что наверное можно, только нужен этот кабель.